# Node.js API real certificates seen as self signed

Tags: node.js, cordova, ssl

i created a Node.js Rest API for a cordova application to help access the MySQL database. The API does not render web pages just sends JSON data to the application. The hosting service provides certificates if you want to buy and i have used them may tmes to make a website HTTPS. The problem is that the API although it uses the correct SSL certificates for the correct domain is seen as having self signed certificates. That is a huge problem because such traffic both HTTp and with self signed certificates is prohibited by android and the app is not working. What can i do? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You could setup a Webserver (like nginx or apache) to act as a reverse proxy. Thus makes the SSL/TLS termination and forward traffic between the client and your API. This is recomendet even if you dont want SSL/TLS, you should avoid to hang node directly on the internet. Always setup a reverse proxy for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/ with your hosting provider, maybe you could use https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/ to act as a proxy in front of your website and have a signed certificate.